# Writing a loop to change the value in a int array with different names

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, input

My title is a bit confusing, but I'm trying to write a loop that will change the value in 81 arrays with different names. I want to either initiated the array with a value or an array of values. This is part of my sudoku solver code since I don't think I'm explaining it well.

```
int cell1[], cell2[9], cell3[9],cell4[9]......cell81[9]; // <-- this will make 81 cells with an array that can hold a possible of 9 candidates

cout << "User input: << endl; // lets use ...1.5...14....67..8...24...63.7..1.9.......3.1..9.52...72...8..26....35...4.9...
                              // as an example
```

Let's assume I store that input into a Char Array and I'm going to use a loop to decide whether to initiate the given value or '.' as an empty value.

For empty values, I'm looking to initialize the array with 1-9 values. I can do this easily with this code.

```
If( ( (int)charArray[ 0 ] - 48) > 0 ) {   // type cast to int. Neg = initialize array with 1-9
                                         // pos = initialize with original value

cell1[ 0 ] =  (int)charArray[ 0 ] - 48;
} else {

cell1[ 9 ] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
}
```

I want to avoid writing this code 81 times for 81 cells ( Considered as writing junk code ). I can't figure out how to write the loop. I'm open to suggestions on how I can code this different using classes, functions, and etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to avoid 2D arrays as much as possible since they seem to cause more problems than solutions. (For me at least)

Comment: If 2D arrays are a problem, then try `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.

Comment: Just one hint. Perhaps it's not necessary to use arrays to represent the numbers. Instead one can use bit mask, because the cell contents really is an unordered *set*. {1,2,3} = 1<<1 + 1<<2 + 1<<3 = 14. (Indexing can as well start from bit 1 instead of 0). If there's only one bit set, then that cell is solved. (To make the testing slightly faster or slightly more obvious, one can use *negative* values to indicate a solved or fixed cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `cell` array as a 2-dimensional array, with 81 rows and 9 columns.

```
int cell[81][9];
```

Now you can loop through them using the syntax `cell[r][c]`. For instance,

```
for( i = 0; i < 81; ++i ) {
  cell[i][0] = 1;
  // ...
  cell[i][8] = 9;
}
```

If you'd prefer to avoid 2-D arrays, you can declare the array as a 1-dimensional array, and just index into it appropriately.

```
int cell[81 * 9];

for( i = 0; i < 81; ++i ) {
  cell[i + 0*81] = 1;
  // ...
  cell[i + 8*81] = 9;
}
```

Comment: very clever. I will have to try this and see how it works with my program. Thanks

Comment: @uBuntunoob Sorry, I totally screwed up the math for converting the subscripts to linear indices. It's fixed now.

Comment: The way you were using before was correct. "cell[ i *81 + 0] = 1". Thanks for the help

Comment: @uBuntunoob Only if you're looping i from [0 .. 8], not the way I have the loop written. Otherwise, when `i == 80` you'd be indexing element `6480`, which is way outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Hm. Ok I'll try it with that code again. Just to be clear. I = position, 0-8 = indices, and 81 = array size?

Comment: @uBuntunoob 81 rows and 9 columns in each row. [Here's](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/tstudio/tech_ref/mi/CAI.htm) a reference that explains calculating linear indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a1[9],a2[9],a3[9],a4[9],...

void init_array(int *ptr, const char *chr, int len, int start){
  for(int i = start; i < len; i++){
     if(chr[i] == '.')continue;
     ptr[i] = chr[i]-'0';//converts character to integer.
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str;
    cin >> str;
    init_array(a1,str.c_str(),9,0); init_array(a2,str.c_str(),9,9/*increment by 9*/);...
    //.. 
    return 0;
}
```

Write a function called `init_array()` that accepts an integer pointer and initializes the array for you. You can avoid duplicating the code this way.